# Preimages of minimal prime ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ and $S$ be commutative rings with unity and $\phi:R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq S$ be an ideal and $\mathfrak{p}$ be a minimal prime ideal containing $\mathfrak{a}$ (in the sense that there is no prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}'\subsetneq\mathfrak{p}$ that contains $\mathfrak{a}$). Must $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ be a minimal prime ideal containing $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{a})$?

I know the answer is yes if $\phi$ is surjective, for then if $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{a})\subseteq\mathfrak{q}\subseteq\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ for a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$, then $\ker\phi\subseteq\mathfrak{q}$ and hence $\mathfrak{q}=\phi^{-1}(\phi(\mathfrak{q}))$. By this and surjectivity, $\phi(\mathfrak{q})$ is a prime ideal and hence must be equal to $\mathfrak{p}$.

For the general case, by factoring as $R\to\operatorname{im}(\phi)\hookrightarrow S$, we can see that it suffices to consider $R$ to be a subring of $S$ and $\phi$ to be the inclusion. From this, I am unable to come up with a proof or a counterexample. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Up to considering quotients by $\mathfrak{a}$ on the right and $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{a})$ on the left, you can indeed assume the map is a ring injection and $\mathfrak{a}=0$. The “going down” theorem then implies the statement when $S$ is flat or integral over $R$.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you for pointing me to the going down theorem, I was not aware of that and I'll look into it.

Comment: A good concept to keep in mind here is the notion of compact minimal prime spectrum for reduced rings. Here I mean minimal prime as in minimal over $(0)$ but it will apply to your question as well. Every reduced ring can be embedded in a Von Neumann Regular ring (there are many such possibilities, but most simply you can take the product of all the localizations at minimal prime ideals). An injection of rings always induces a surjection on minimal prime spectra, and if $R \subseteq S$ and the minimal primes of $S$ contract to minimal primes of $R$ then actually you get a homeomorphism thereon

Comment: Since $S$ is $0$-dimensional in this case, it's (minimal) prime spectrum is compact and this would imply that $R$ has compact minimal prime spectrum. However, most reduced rings do not have compact minimal prime spectrum. For example, consider the ring $R$ which has elements $a + b$ where $a \in \mathbb{F}_2$ and $b \in \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{F}_2$, with multiplication defined in the natural way.  There are lots of simple ad hoc counterexamples to your question too, which others might want to mention, but I think this is a good theoretical reason to keep in your pocket.